# Call Method in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, asynchronous, afhttprequestoperation

I'm trying to update my database after I get my data in my webservice but it doesn't work and I dont know why... here My Code..

```
 - (void) getCurrentVersion {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:@"http://www.sample.com/api/getdata"
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
             NSDictionary *versionJson = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
             networkBase = [versionJson objectForKey:@"NetworkBase"];
             baseVersion = [versionJson objectForKey:@"Version"];
             [db insertData:networkBase withVersion:baseVersion];
             NSLog(@"getCurrentVersion %@ %@",networkBase,baseVersion);
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
             NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
             NSLog(@"%@",errorMessage);

         }];


}
```

Here's the code for db

```
 - (void)insertData:(NSString *)networkBase withVersion:(NSString *)version{
    const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement2;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE version SET message = '%@', storeversion = '%@' WHERE id = 1",networkBase,version];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            if (sqlite3_step(statement2) == SQLITE_DONE ) {
                NSLog(@"Inserting Success!");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));
            }

        }
            }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement2);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);

}
```

so my problem is with this line

```
[db insertData:networkBase withVersion:baseVersion];
NSLog(@"getCurrentVersion %@ %@",networkBase,baseVersion);
```

it executes NSLog but not the [db insertdata]

Comment: Did you debug your `insertData:withVersion` method? Does the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeed?

Comment: Hmmmm @rmdaddy you're right my sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed